# How to create a matrix of characters with numpy broadcasting, meshgrid or other method

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Say I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array(['a','b'])
b = np.array(['c','d'])
```

How can I create a grid like:

```
ac | ad
-------
bc | bd
```

I'd love  to be able to do:

`a @ b`

or

`np.meshgrid(a,b)`

But both throw type exceptions.

What's an efficient way to create the combination using an operator like a matrix product? Itertools.product is one way but I'd prefer to use numpy.

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With object dtype (instead of the default `U1`), `+` is string join:

```
In [317]: a.astype(object)[:,None]+ b.astype(object)                                                         
Out[317]: 
array([['ac', 'ad'],
       ['bc', 'bd']], dtype=object)
```

Since this is working object dtype arrays, the speed won't be as good as pure numeric code.  It might even be slower than a list comprehension.

```
In [319]: np.array([[i+j for j in b] for i in a])                                                            
Out[319]: 
array([['ac', 'ad'],
       ['bc', 'bd']], dtype='<U2')
```

timings:

```
In [320]: timeit np.array([[i+j for j in b] for i in a])                                                     
10.9 µs ± 130 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [321]: timeit a.astype(object)[:,None]+ b.astype(object)                                                  
16.7 µs ± 206 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and a pure list version:

```
In [322]: %%timeit A,B=a.tolist(), b.tolist() 
     ...: [[i+j for j in B] for i in A]                                                                                               
1.33 µs ± 13.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

`char.add` while convenient, still depends on string methods, so isn't faster:

```
In [324]: timeit np.char.add(a[:, None], b)                                                                  
15.6 µs ± 62.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`frompyfunc` with `operator.__add__` is slightly better than the list comprehension:

```
In [331]: timeit np.frompyfunc(__add__,2,1)(a[:,None], b)                                                    
8.75 µs ± 182 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [`np.char.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.add.html#numpy.char.add)

---

```
np.char.add(a[:, None], b)
```

```
array([['ac', 'ad'],
       ['bc', 'bd']], dtype='<U2')
```